# Selenium Webdriver - Able to locate elements through firebug, but getting nosuchelementexception at Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What happens is that I have this webpage:
[image: main1]
The following `div` is what's visible in cyan in the screenshot above. I've circled the bit of text I'm trying to find:
[image]

I've tried Xpath and CSS. They both work in Firebug and they both locate the elements fine inside this floating div. But when I run my script, I get the nosuchelement exception.

-Things I'm suspicious of:

1. As you can see, this div is a call to another webpage (indicated by
   the whole html tree inside the div). This might be the reason
   Webdriver goes to hell and doesn't find anything. But I have no idea
   how to tell it to look in this window.
2. The div acts like a floating pop-up, graying out the rest of the
   background page. Not sure if that has anything to do, but it might be
   causing trouble too.

I don't think it's necessary, but here is one of the CSS locators that I'm using in Firepath and works in locating the 5040 text.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".feature>tbody>tr>td[width='312']")
```

So the question here is: how do I locate this text in these `td`'s if my xpath/css locators work manually but not with WebDriver?

Comment: You probably need to switch to the iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that `iframe` element - it is the reason you are getting the exception.

You need to switch to `iframe` before finding an element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Content")
```

Or (in case it is not working due to spaces in the `id`):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id$=Content]"));
```

Comment: And remember do switch back from the iframe to the default content, if you need to go back.

Comment: The spaces are there because I whited them out. Thanks though! Trying out your answer as we speak.

Comment: @patricmj is that through driver.switchTo().parentFrame(); ?

Comment: @zuri it would be `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`. And thanks, patricmj, good point!